# How do 2D painting softwares handle rotations of raster graphics?

Tags: c++, paint, photoshop

I am programming a small 2D painting software, but I'm not entirely sure about how to handle rotations -- right now I have implemented:

```
 float new_x = (cos(rad)*nx - sin(rad)*ny) + resolution_X/2;
 float new_y = (sin(rad)*nx + cos(rad)*ny) + resolution_Y/2;
```

This code simply rotates the selected pixels around the center of the canvas. Though, if I do this operation multiple times, I do end up distorting the image.

Of course this is due to the image being fundamentally discrete in nature and the implied rounding errors.

If you take a look at any decent painting/image editing software, they some how minimize this loss of information, does anyone have an idea how?

Comment: You may keep original copy, and rotate it on the screen. Let every further operation deal with original copy to prevent loss of data. Then data loss is limited to once.

Comment: You are likely to end up with aliasing errors and even gaps, when you map old position to new position and then write a pixel there.  Chances are that any sane painting program will perform a raster operation on the rotated rectangle, using the inverse transform to map each destination pixel coordinate back to the original image and then perform resampling (e.g. nearest neighbor, linear interpolation, bicubic interpolation, etc) based on what fractional part of the source pixel coordinate you land on.  The result will still be an approximation.  The above comment about keeping original applies